# Saving to a share drive exe

Tags: vb.net

Alright, so here is what I have, I have created a dashboard interface for my team to streamline a process that used to be manual.  All the information entered here occasionally needs to transfer hands.  Right now the .exe is standalone and accessed by all of the team members through a share drive.  call it drive s

Team members have created a shortcut to s:/dashboard.exe and all pull from the same dashboard (makes it easier for me to streamline updates) .. today I implemented a feature which I thought was going to go more smoothly than it did.  I created a save function using My.Settings

It looks like this

`Private Sub HandoffToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles HandoffToolStripMenuItem.Click
        My.Settings.SaveIncident = IncidentBox.Text
        My.Settings.SaveNumber = IncidentNum.Text
        My.Settings.SaveOpened = OpenedCall.CheckState
        My.Settings.SaveAnnounced = AnnouncedIC.CheckState
        My.Settings.SaveImpact = ImpactReport.CheckState
        My.Settings.SaveOC = OCBox.CheckState
        My.Settings.SaveSent = CheckBox6.CheckState
        My.Settings.SaveExec = CheckBox3.CheckState
        My.Settings.SaveCFAM = CBCFAM.CheckState
        My.Settings.SaveCFEC = CBCFEC.CheckState
        My.Settings.SaveCCMC = CBCCMC.CheckState
        My.Settings.SaveCORE = CBCORE.CheckState
        My.Settings.SaveFEIN = CBFEIN.CheckState
        My.Settings.SaveFORE = CBFORE.CheckState
        My.Settings.SaveFRAN = CBFRANK.CheckState
        My.Settings.SaveGLEN = CBGLEN.CheckState
        My.Settings.SaveHUNT = CBHUNT.CheckState
        My.Settings.SaveLENO = CBLENO.CheckState
        My.Settings.SaveLIJM = CBLIJ.CheckState
        My.Settings.SaveLIJB = CBBED.CheckState
        My.Settings.SaveNSUH = CBNSUH.CheckState
        My.Settings.SavePlAI = CBPLAI.CheckState
        My.Settings.SaveSOUT = CBSOUT.CheckState
        My.Settings.SaveSIUHN = CBSIUN.CheckState
        My.Settings.SaveSIUHS = CBSIUS.CheckState
        My.Settings.SaveSYOS = CBSYOS.CheckState
        My.Settings.SaveZUCK = CBZUCK.CheckState
        My.Settings.SaveLIHO = CBLIJH.CheckState
        My.Settings.SavePANS = CBMEDI.CheckState
        My.Settings.SaveMembers = CallMembers.Text
        My.Settings.SaveTRIGM = Minute.Text
        My.Settings.SaveTRIGS = Seconds.Text
        My.Settings.SaveBRIDM = BM.Text
        My.Settings.SaveBRIDS = BS.Text
        My.Settings.SaveEXECM = EM.Text
        My.Settings.SaveEXECS = ES.Text
        My.Settings.SaveTimeline = TimeLine.Text
        Me.Close()
    End Sub`

that is the code for the save

Here is where we pull it back into the variables

`Private Sub Dashboard_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Me.ToolTip1.SetToolTip(Me.CTOText, "Clicking this will send a text to the CTO")
        Me.ToolTip1.SetToolTip(Me.resolveText, "This will send a resolution text")
        Me.ToolTip1.SetToolTip(Me.SMSBtn, "This will send a text to SLBackupAlert")
        Me.ToolTip1.SetToolTip(Me.Complete, "This will output an e-mail timeline to the IC")
        Me.ToolTip1.SetToolTip(Me.LdrBTN, "This will populate regional directors based on sites selected")
        'Handoff'
        IncidentBox.Text = My.Settings.SaveIncident
        IncidentNum.Text = My.Settings.SaveNumber
        OpenedCall.CheckState = My.Settings.SaveOpened
        AnnouncedIC.CheckState = My.Settings.SaveAnnounced
        ImpactReport.CheckState = My.Settings.SaveImpact
        OCBox.CheckState = My.Settings.SaveOC
        CheckBox6.CheckState = My.Settings.SaveSent
        CheckBox3.CheckState = My.Settings.SaveExec
        CBCFAM.CheckState = My.Settings.SaveCFAM
        CBCFEC.CheckState = My.Settings.SaveCFEC
        CBCCMC.CheckState = My.Settings.SaveCCMC
        CBCORE.CheckState = My.Settings.SaveCORE
        CBFEIN.CheckState = My.Settings.SaveFEIN
        CBFORE.CheckState = My.Settings.SaveFORE
        CBFRANK.CheckState = My.Settings.SaveFRAN
        CBGLEN.CheckState = My.Settings.SaveGLEN
        CBHUNT.CheckState = My.Settings.SaveHUNT
        CBLENO.CheckState = My.Settings.SaveLENO
        CBLIJ.CheckState = My.Settings.SaveLIJM
        CBBED.CheckState = My.Settings.SaveLIJB
        CBNSUH.CheckState = My.Settings.SaveNSUH
        CBPLAI.CheckState = My.Settings.SavePlAI
        CBSOUT.CheckState = My.Settings.SaveSOUT
        CBSIUN.CheckState = My.Settings.SaveSIUHN
        CBSIUS.CheckState = My.Settings.SaveSIUHS
        CBSYOS.CheckState = My.Settings.SaveSYOS
        CBZUCK.CheckState = My.Settings.SaveZUCK
        CBLIJH.CheckState = My.Settings.SaveLIHO
        CBMEDI.CheckState = My.Settings.SavePANS
        CallMembers.Text = My.Settings.SaveMembers
        Minute.Text = My.Settings.SaveTRIGM
        Seconds.Text = My.Settings.SaveTRIGS
        BM.Text = My.Settings.SaveBRIDM
        BS.Text = My.Settings.SaveBRIDS
        EM.Text = My.Settings.SaveEXECM
        ES.Text = My.Settings.SaveEXECS
        TimeLine.Text = My.Settings.SaveTimeline`

Once I pull the variables it works perfectly on my machine, when I grab my dashboard it will have the variables if saved correctly.. However I assumed this was saving to the .exe so when anyone opened s:/dashboard.exe they would pull the most recent copy anyone had saved.. Instead it is pulling their most recent saved copy even though it is a share drive.

Is there any way to get this to save to the .exe so anyone accessing the file in the share drive can pull the same information?

Basically if User 1 saves it on User 1's computer I want User 2 to be able to grab it from the s:/ drive with User 1's data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to specifically write it to your `s:` drive using some other I/O mechanism.  The `Settings` class only allows writing settings at the user level, which are persisted within your local users folders.

Answer (score 0):

As @James mentioned, 'my.setting' is not the right place for this. What I like to do is write these as XML using a datatable.

```
<!-- language: lang-vb -->
'Declare a DataTable public to your application
Public MySettings As New DataTable

'On load of your form or application, load the existing setting if they exist
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'If you don't supply a full path for your file, the path will be the same as your EXE.
    If System.IO.File.Exists("MySettings.xml") Then
        'File exists, read from it
        MySettings.ReadXml("MySettings.xml")
    Else
        'File does not exist, define it here
        'Create the schema for the table
        MySettings.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("SaveIncident", GetType(String)))
        MySettings.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("SaveNumber", GetType(String)))
        'Create you one record
        MySettings.Rows.Add(MySettings.NewRow)
        'Set Default values
        MySettings.Rows(0)("SaveIncident") = ""
        MySettings.Rows(0)("SaveNumber") = ""
        'You may want to save it so it is out there now
        'MySettings.WriteXml("MySettings.xml")
    End If
    'Set your variables if you want to use them
    With MySettings.Rows(0)
        IncidentBox.Text = .Item("SaveIncident")
        IncidentNum.Text = .Item("SaveNumber")

    End With
End Sub
'Here the settings are being saved on close of the form but you should do this through a save button or something.
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    With MySettings.Rows(0)
        .Item("SaveIncident") = IncidentBox.Text
        .Item("SaveNumber") = IncidentNum.Text
    End With
    MySettings.WriteXml("MySettings.xml")
End Sub
```

Note: This is NOT multi-user friendly. The last person to save will overwrite anyone else's changes. This should only be used for things that rarely change.

Also, with this method, you can open the XML in something like NotePad and edit it. So you can change settings without having to open the exe.

Comment: I understand what you are getting at broadly but can you apply what I have from the code provided to give me a better idea for how to export these settings? I want it to write all of that to the XML and save it on the S drive so another user can pick it up and ultimately rewrite the XML file if necessary. Its essentially transferring the form data to another user over a share drive. All of the variables I am trying to transfer are listed above in my initial pos.

Comment: I changed it a little so it has 2 of your variable names. This should get you started.

Comment: Steve I'm just having a little difficulty realiizing where the rest will go.. You started a column called SaveIncident and SaveNumber but that would mean each setting would get a column, should it really be columns SaveName and SaveAttribute SaveName being the name of whats bieng saved IE SaveIncident and SaveAttribute being the textbox like Incidentbox.text

Comment: Can you add a few more save items so I can get an idea for how it is functioning?

Comment: I took your code with your variable names, if you want to change them, go for it. The current code is one column for one setting and there is always one record. There are other ways to save your settings too, do some research, play with the code I gave you.

Comment: Yes Steve, I really appreciate your help, what I meant was could you add a varialbe or two from my original code so I can distinguish how to add secnd and third rows etc.